# How do I reference an object property in an anonymous function within the same object?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```
var foo = {
  x: 1,
  y: (function () {
     return ++this.x;
  })()
};
console.log(foo.y); // undefined rather than 2
```

Let's say that **I want to be able to reference foo.y without using foo.y()**. Is that possible?

The above obviously doesn't work, and I'm assuming it is because closure references a different *this*.

Comment: It doesn't "change" `this` at all, it is an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression), and doesn't get any other `this` context other than the global `this`, which is probably `window`, if you're working within the browser, as it seems you are.

Comment: are you wanting to foo.y to always return whatever x is as x changes, or just what it was initialized as?

Comment: @BradHarris Yes, let's say, for example, I wanted foo.y to always contain the value of ++this.x at any given moment, but I didn't want to use parens (e.g. foo.y()).

Comment: @oevna Your question is "How can I invoke a function without using ()?"

Comment: @LarryBattle Not at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to access y as a property and not a function, and have it return the current value of foo.x, the only way I can think of is using getters/setters, which is part of the ES5 spec, and adopted in most of the modern browsers (but not really useable if you're supporting older browsers).

```
var foo = {
    x: 1,
    get y() {
        return this.x;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't declare y as function, but as a result of a function call. It should be:

```
var foo = {
  x: 1,
  y: function () {
     return this.x;
  }
};
```

Or, if you want just to assign to y value of x:

```
 var foo = {
    x: 1,
    y: this.x
 };
```

UPDATE: It is NOT possible to make y synonym of x. When you declare y - it can be a value or a function. It cannot be a reference to another value.

Comment: That assigns a function to y, not the value of x. In your example, I would have to use foo.y().

Comment: Then simply y: this.x if you want just value, but not a function.

Comment: That would work, it's just not what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm trying to assign the return value of a function to a property while referencing properties from that same object within that function.

Comment: You cannot do that. Only the first example in my answer. No other way.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just return x directly if you don't want to use y() as a function? The only reason why you would return a function is you actually need to modify x's result.

```
var foo = {
     x: 1,
     y: (function () {
          return this.x;
     })()}; 
console.log(foo.x); // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`foo.y` isn't a function. `foo.y` is defined as `foo.x`.

Comment: I should have been clearer. I want to be able to reference foo.y, not foo.y(). The example code I provided was my failed attempt to accomplish that. I could remove the closure, remove the "instant call" to the anonymous function, and foo.y() would work, but that isn't the behavior I'm seeking.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how you would like to reference foo.y?

Comment: I revised my original question.

Answer (score 0):

```
var foo = new Object();
foo.x = 1;
foo.y = function() { return this.x; };
console.log(foo.y());
```

or if you're trying to invoke `y` while you define foo:

```
var foo = new Object();
foo.x = 1;
foo.y = x;
console.log(foo.y);
```

Comment: Your first example uses foo.y(), and the second doesn't put the return value of a function into foo.y.

Comment: My second example was effectively what your example does. You have an immediately executing function that sets it value to y which is the same as x.

Comment: Sorry, I provided a confusing example. x could be anything referencing another property of the same object; for example, the value of x incremented by 1 (in my updated example).